# Java: ¿Cómo detectar estado de un elemento en el servidor (máquina de estados) cuando envío varias peticiones desde el cliente?

Tags: java, state

Tengo parte cliente (vue/js) y parte servidora (java). En la parte servidora tengo implementada una máquina de estados como la del post https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2011/08/12/state-machine/?unapproved=124486&moderation-hash=2b1744975f6447c321e0c02567862418#comment-124486

En la parte cliente se pueden lanzar determinadas acciones al servidor y éste va cambiando de estado.
En un momento determinado, ese servidor necesita enviar una confirmación al cliente de la acción que solicitó hacer y el cliente debe enviarle la respuesta a esa acción.

Problema: Si el cliente lanza varias acciones al servidor del mismo tipo y el servidor envía confirmación al cliente, en la vuelta ¿cómo detecto que transacción es la que mandó solicitar la confirmación (si hay varias en curso)?

Gracias de antemano.